# Dual statement to the fundamental theorem of group homomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, commutative-algebra, category-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ and $H$ be groups. The fundamental theorem of group homomophism states that, for any surjection $f : G \to H$, there exists an isomorphism $\eta : G/\text{ker}(f) \to H$.

I am wondering if there exists a dual statement to this theorem: starting with an injection $f : G \to H$. It would be interesting to see $\text{im}(f)$ (or the cokernel of some map) appearing instead of $\text{ker}(f)$, in some way.

I've read that surjections and injections exist in opposite categories; I've thus tagged 'category theory', for potential reasoning in this area.

Comment: Just so I can see what you're searching for, you want a function $\psi: G \to H/\operatorname{im}(f),$ perhaps? I don't have enough experience in this area, but it seems a good question.

Comment: That would be interesting -- I'm interested in anything justifiable as being a dual statement.

Comment: There's more to the FT than that: we also have that $f=\bar{\eta}\circ \pi$ where $\pi$ is the canonical projection on the quotient. I think you should reverse all the arrows in that little triangle and see what you should be proving.

Comment: I don't know if it is a dual statement in a categorical sense but $f:G\to im(f)$ is an isomorphism for injective $f.$

Comment: I think the isomorphism theorem is already selfdual. It can be stated as an isomorphism $\text{coim}(f) \cong \text{im}(f)$ (or rather that the canonical map is an isomorphism). Hence you get the same by dualizing.

Comment: To emphasize, Con offers the right perspective on the isomorphism theorem. The special case of the isomorphism theorem in the OP is the case for surjective $f$. The dual case will be the special case of the isomorphism theorem for injective $f$ (because injective is the dual condition to surjective and the isomorphism theorem is selfdual), which is precisely Stewan's suggestion.

Comment: Are we sure that the image is normal in $H$, so that $H/im(f)$ is a (quotient) group?

Comment: @Devo It's not.

Comment: @Con Seems to be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can dualize the fundamental theorem on homomorphisms in its more general form. It states that for a surjective homomorphism of groups $p : G \twoheadrightarrow Q$, a homomorphism $f : G \to H$ factors through $p$ (i.e., we have $f = \overline{f} \circ p$ for some homomorphism $\overline{f} : Q \to H$) if and only if $\ker(p) \subseteq \ker(f)$. This applies, in particular, to the special case of the projection $p : G \twoheadrightarrow G/N$ with $\ker(p) = N$, in which we get the usual statement that $f : G \to H$ factors through $G \twoheadrightarrow G/N$ iff $N \subseteq \ker(f)$.

The dualization is as follows: If $i : U \hookrightarrow G$ is an injective homomorphism of groups, then a homomorphism of groups $f : H \to G$ factors through $i$ (i.e., $f = i \circ \overline{f}$ for some homomorphism $\overline{f} : H \to U$) if and only if $\mathrm{im}(f) \subseteq \mathrm{im}(i)$. This applies, in particular, to the special case of an inclusion map of a subgroup $U \subseteq G$. So here, $f : H \to G$ factors through $U \hookrightarrow G$ if and only if $\mathrm{im}(f) \subseteq U$.

This dual statement is very easy to prove and often tacitly used, but usually not stated explicitly in textbooks on group theory or algebra, probably because it is *so obvious*.

These statements are, in fact, dual to each other, since the first one is a criterion for factoring homomorphisms through epimorphisms of groups, whereas the second one is about monomorphisms of groups.

Similar statements hold for *all algebraic structures* (sets, rings, abelian groups, lattices, Lie algebras, etc.). Here, the kernel has to be replaced by the kernel congruence relation $\ker(f) := \{(x,x') : f(x)=f(x')\}$, but the image stays the same.

But the statements do not hold verbatim for, say, topological spaces. The first statement holds in $\mathbf{Top}$ iff $Q$ carries the final topology with respect to $q$, and the second statement holds iff $U$ carries the initial topology with respect to $i$ (because we need $\overline{f}$ to be continuous in each case).

Comment: I'm wondering: does the surjection $p : G \to Q$ give rise to an injection $i_p : Q \to G$, that preserves/reverses the properties of $p$, in some way?

Comment: Not at all for $\mathbf{Grp}$. Please consider simple examples.